# The priority between two Categories

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have two Categories(c1 and c2) for a Class, they both has the same method 
-(void)run 
when I send message to this method,why the responder always be the c2 Category?
I think they should have the same priority.

Comment: What do you mean by priority? Would you expect both methods to be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods in class categories are added to the class in the order in which they are found.  A method with the same name (selector) as an existing method will simply replace the earlier implementation with that of the newly-found method.

There are no guarantees on the order in which categories will be processed, so never rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

The final class have only one realisation with name **run**. What exact realisation have this name depends by compiler. Other realisation will have some other name. You can look on methods in runtime to undarstand what i mean.